# IndexError: list index out of range while using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, indexing, index-error

```
# Find all course summaries
summaries = soup.find_all("div", class_="course-summary-card")
summaries[0]
```

Output:
[image]

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-62-01693c759680> in <module>()
          1 # Find all course summaries
          2 summaries = soup.find_all("div", class_="course-summary-card")
    ----> 3 summaries[0]

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well it means that there is no such `div`, hence you can not obtain the first...

Comment: There's not even a question. Just two lines of code and a traceback. I somehow feel like a Rest-API on SO sometimes.

Comment: Yes, correct. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

If `summaries[0]` is out of range, then `summaries` must be an empty list. This because there is no `"div"` in your course summaries.

Answer (score 2):

this mean `summaries` is an empty list. you can check using `len()`

here an example of your problem :

```
>>> s=[]
>>> len(s)
0
>>> s[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then you can use just `if` to check that the list is not empty:

```
>>> s=[]
>>> if s: 
...     print 'ok'
... 
>>> s=[1]
>>> if s: 
...     print 'ok'
... 
ok
```